# Why plot returns empty in this example?

Tags: plotting

Let me rewrite this question, showing the original problem, as it is more subtle than the simple example I showed before using `Sin[t]`. Here we go again.

When I write this:

```
foo[$s_,$t_]:=Module[{s=$s,t=$t,r},
r= OutputResponse[TransferFunctionModel[Evaluate[1/(s^2+2*s+1)],s],UnitStep[t],t];
Plot[Chop@First@r,{t,0,20}]
];
foo[s, t]
```

I get an empty plot.  But when I write this

```
foo[s_,t_]:=Module[{r},
r= Chop@First@OutputResponse[TransferFunctionModel[1/(s^2+2*s+1),s],UnitStep[t],t];
Plot[r,{t,0,20}]
];
foo[s, t]
```

I do not get an empty plot.

My question is: Why first example above does not produce a plot?

I know it has to do with how 's' and 't', the free parameters, to the calls to `TransferFunctionModel[]`  and `OutputResponse[]`. But I do not see exactly why that is.

thanks,

Comment: It's good to see you are back, Nasser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first example, the `Plot` is inside a `Module` that localizes `t` into something like `t$23`. So, when you run `foo[s, t]`, you are actually running something similar to

```
 t$23=t;
 r=E^-t$23 UnitStep[t$23];
 Plot[Chop@First@r,{t$23,0,20}]
```

The second line returns an expression of `t`. When you insert it in the last `Plot`, it doesn't run properly, because, the `{t$23, ...}` argument in `Plot` is held, it doesn't evaluate to `t` before plotting.

In the second example, however, you don't have this problem. `r` becomes an expression of whatever variable `p` you call in `foo[s, p]` (`t` in this case), and that's the same variable you are using in your `Plot`. Even if `Plot` holds its arguments, so it's "immune to evaluation", it's not immune to the lexical replacement `Module` does.

First example analogy:

```
Module[{x = x2},
 {x, Hold[x]}]

{x2, Hold[x$14454]}
```

Second example analogy:

```
Module[{},
 {x, Hold[x]}]

{x, Hold[x]}
```

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi, edited. See if it's clearer now